# Neo4J - Rolling up values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to do the following:

1. Traverse a tree level by level
2. Check if a particular property exists at current level
3. If it exists, return it. The sum of all the elements at this level should be assigned to the parent's price property
4. If not, go to the next level and start over with step 2. If it reaches the lowest level then get it from the RoomType assigned to the room , assign this value to it's price property and roll up the values.

Initial graph:
[image]

Graph after query:
[image]

Assume price property doesn't exist before running  the query

This is what I have come up with but don't know how to continue.

```
MATCH (b:Building) 
SET b.price = 
   CASE WHEN has(b.price) THEN b.price
   ELSE 
     // Go to the next level, compute price for all children and assign the sum of children to b.price. 
   END
 RETURN b
```

Comment: There is no iterative approach :) But I'll update with something that can work

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
MATCH (parent:Building)
WHERE not has(parent.price)
match (parent)-->(child)
WITH parent, sum(child.price) as price
SET parent.price = price
```

#### Update

```
MATCH path=(root:Building)-[*0..]->(parent)-->(child)
WITH parent,child, length(path) as l
ORDER BY l desc
WITH parent, sum(child.price) as price
SET parent.price = coalesce( parent.price, price)
```

Comment: I have added an image for more clarity. Initially, Building, Floor and Room will not have 'price' property. It will be assigned the first time the query is executed. Hope this makes sense.